# Correlation between multiple azure app insight telemetries

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, telemetry

We know that we can correlate the operations within an Azure App Insight resource using the operation Id and parent operation Id.

We have multiple app services, function apps running in Azure and we would like to track an operation that is triggered from one app service and ended in another app service. I don't think would be possible by default in Azure as the Azure backend wouldn't know about this.

I hope we can add custom props to the telemetry and track this across all app insights.

Is there a way to do this or has anyone somehow achieved this?

For example, I want to track a login from my angular app to an API then to a Token validation system(another API), and then back to the angular app. My expected output,

| timestamp | operationId | parent operationId | name | itemType | app insight name |

Comment: If you add the full application insights integration to your application, it will track calls even across application insights instances without any further action on your part. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

Comment: Yes, by default, the requests and dependencies are logged in App Insights when the code is running in the Azure Infrastructure as App Service, Function apps, or as any app. But what about client apps and apps that are not running in Azure and are in the operation flow? Any custom props should be sent through the flow right?

Comment: The correlation has nothing to do with whether app runs in Azure infra or not. You can create 2 webapps, one calling another, run them locally and still see telemetry correlated automatically.